# Why are my error logs full of 404s for "adult" content?

Tags: spam, http-status-code-404

Idly perusing my site's error logs this morning, I was *shocked* to discover that a large number of rather explicit had been requested. (I don't mind telling you that I very nearly sprayed my cold brew all over the screen!)

```
2020-05-08 02:16:13 UTC [apache][core:info] [pid 42603] [client 66.249.66.88:35734] AH00128: File does not exist: /home/u88-8bxzcuafdah3/www/mysite.com/public_html/something-very-rude

2020-05-08 02:06:45 UTC [apache][core:info] [pid 63958] [client 66.249.66.88:49358] AH00128: File does not exist: /home/u88-8bxzcuafdah3/www/mysite.com/public_html/something-very-rude

2020-05-08 01:47:49 UTC [apache][core:info] [pid 3909] [client 66.249.66.90:40304] AH00128: File does not exist: /home/u88-8bxzcuafdah3/www/mysite.com/public_html/something-very-rude
```

And there are *loads* of them. It looks relentless. They are spaced about 10 mins apart, but it does vary. Likewise the IP addresses do change, but they are all in the 66.249.66.0 range.

Presumably this is something related to referrer spam, but I can't work out the motive. I'm pretty sure it's not something to worry about, but it is a bit confusing...

What's going on here?

Comment: Because random crawlers try random content. Welcome to the internet.

Comment: Sounds like a random crawler (check for the user agent header). Could be a typo in another crawled webseite (that now points unwillingly to your site), too. This is just how the internet works.